# Filter per year with a timestamp on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm having some trouble with filtering for a specific year with a timestamp.

This is the code I have to convert the timestamp into the yyyy-mm-dd format:

SELECT rating, timestamp,
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as datetime,
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date) AS date_value
FROM ratings;

Result from this query:
[image: result from this query]

Then I tried to extract the ratings for the year 2000 with

- WHERE year=2000
- WHERE date_value >= 2000-01-01 AND date_value <= 2000-12-31
- HAVING date_value >= 2000-01-01 AND date_value <= 2000-12-31
- HAVING year=2000

Nothing seems to work. Could you help me with this please? Here is a picture of my database if it can help: [image: db]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT rating, timestamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as datetime, 
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date) AS date_value FROM ratings
WHERE year(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as date) )=2000  ;
```

Comment: thank you very much!